# Not able to export an app for app store distribution or adhoc distribution?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, ipa, ad-hoc-distribution

Can anyone tell why below given error occurs while exporting an archive for app store distribution or adhoc distribution?

> Your developer account needs to be updated. Please visit the Member
>   Center. https://developer.apple.com/membercenter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I google this problem and found below given solution for this issue.

> **There was one apple id added in xcode preferences which was not valid
>   as an apple developer  account.**

I simply removed that account and its worked for me.

Comment: reference for this answer is -: https://www.andyibanez.com/developer-account-needs-updated-fix/

Answer (score 3):

I am the guy who wrote the article linked in the previous answer. That may be an issue, but there's another thing that may cause this to happen.

If you have already checked your XCode for Apple accounts that are no developers and you're still receiving that message, make sure you have accepted all your contracts in the developer portal. Everytime iOS is updated, the contracts are updated as well and you gotta accept them again. If you don't accept the new contracts this error will continue popping up.

Comment: Keep in mind that both your developer account AND your company's "agent" needs to accept all new agreements. Logging in to https://developer.apple.com/membercenter with any applicable accounts should instantly show you any agreements you need to accept.